# System.exit(0) does not work for closing application

Tags: android

Because my application is fully dependent to SD memory, I want to close my application when SD card removed. I can find out when SD card removed but when I want to close my application using

```
System.exit(0)
```

application doesn't close and this error shown in my activity

```
appname isn't responding. Do you want to close it?
```

I guess its waiting for some processes to close.
how can I fully close my application like in Task Manager.
This is my code:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
am.killBackgroundProcesses("packegename");

System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);
System.exit(0);
```

Can anybody help me

UPDATE : 
I should say that I have two services running in background

Comment: did you use `finish();`?

Comment: Do not invent your own ways to close the app, use `Activity.finish()`. Plus handle sd card removal properly, may be show a dialog to user that sd card is removed and now m gonna close.

Comment: As M-WaJeEh posted, use `Activity.finish()` instead of `System.exit()` AND read over [Quitting an application - is that frowned upon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon) for why.

Comment: I used finish() but it didn't work for me. I can use Activity.finish() but there are some services that I want to stop them. The services work with SD card

Answer (score 1):

Since your Facing [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) ,I would suggest instead of killing the Background Process ,you can try to kill the app by using killProcess() as i shown below and then execute exit method in onDestory() of your activity.

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: Actually KillProcess worked like System.exit(0) for me

Comment: What does the halting problem have to do with this question? :)

Comment: @latto: Since he is not sure whether the app is running or not, That's one i have refereed as Halting problem

Answer (score 0):

```
System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);
```

this will caused the system to finalize all the resources for this reason you are getting error.

Hope this will help you.